# How to detect whether or not the housing activity has been paused from a View?

Tags: android, android-view

I need to detect whenever the activity that houses a `View` I'm creating has been pushed to background (i.e., no longer visible to the users).

I've tried overriding `onDetachedFromWindow()` but it didn't brought the result I was hoping to see despite what its [official docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onDetachedFromWindow()) say:

> protected void **onDetachedFromWindow()**
>
> This is called when the view is detached from a window. *At this point it no longer has a surface for drawing*.

I for one assumed that by going into the background, the `View` will *no longer has a surface for drawing* (as it is now covered by another `View`). But this turned out not the case.

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: when onPause() is called it means the activity is no longer in the foreground, why do you need onDetachedFromWindow?

Comment: I need to do some cleanup within the `View` itself.

Comment: just do the cleanup in `onPause()`

Comment: No. The stuff is internal within the `View` and I would rather not giving the responsibility to an external control (e.g., the activity that contains it).

Comment: ah so you have a custom view, and you want to do clean up in the class of this custom view,when the activity housing this view goes to `onPause()` yes?

Comment: Yep. But I'd prefer not to have my activities doing it. The `View` should handle all of its needs itself.

Comment: may I know what kind of clean up are you planning to do?

Answer (score 1):

After digging out the docs for `View`, I've finally found my solution.

Being pushed to the background doesn't instantly mean that a view will be detached from its window. (It very well might, but just not the second you/your user trigger an activity change.)

One method that would always be called the moment your view is being overlaid by another view (like when you change activities) is `onWindowFocusChanged()`.

You could rely on this option for things like unsubscribing Rx `Observables` (like what I did) and the likes.

Answer (score -1):

You need to override the onStop() method on the activity.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more? I need to override `onStop()` and then what?